# submit a form without using a submit button

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to submit this for without using a submit button. Here I have used javascript and once the form has submitted user should be directed to the **B.php**.

**html code**

```
   <form id="jsform" action="B.php" method="POST" target="_blank"> 
       <input type="hidden" value="test" name="title"/>                          
   </form>
```

**java-script  code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementById('jsform').submit();
</script>
```

These 2 code lines run separately but not running together. Any mistakes have I done.

Comment: It's probably running afoul of your browser's popup blocker.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: try 
`$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#jsform').submit();
});
`

Comment: You can submit the form without submit button but you need to have some fields (without hidden field) so that you can add change or click event to it.

Comment: You `Javascript` code looks good, and it should work. Did you got any error in `console`..?

Comment: Drop `target="_blank"` and it should be working

Comment: See example here ~ https://jsfiddle.net/ubujujc0/. Your browser will most probably show a "popup blocked" message

Answer (score 2):

In javascript you can do this:

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("jsform").submit(); // using ID
}
```

And with jQuery

```
$(function() {
  $("#jsform").submit(); // using ID
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I write my comment as an actual answer this time.

Drop `target="_blank"` and it should work just fine. Otherwise your browser might see it as a popup.

Also make sure your JS is run after your form.

Answer (score 0):

Use form name to submit

```
document.myform.submit();
```